# Add Collapsible Sidebar Menu to Drupal Bootstrap Theme

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal, drupal-7

I created a sub-theme of the Drupal Bootstrap theme and I wanted to move the default top-level nav menu to the sidebar with the the ability to collapse. [This theme](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/) is exactly what I want, but it's not optimized for Drupal 7.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You might want to take a look at the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to ask a better question

Comment: I can use some css hacks to make the navbar appear beside the page and add js to make it collapse, I was just seeing if someone else has attempted to create a collapsible sidebar menu with the Bootstrap 3 theme  for Drupal so I didn't duplicate my efforts. 

tl;dr: Have you made a collapsible sidebar nav with the Bootstrap 3 theme for Drupal? Let me know!

Answer (score 2):

There are two modules that will do this for you also you can do this manually with any javascript menu you like.

Both of these modules you will have to alter the template to override the default Bootstrap collapse, this is well documented for both Druapl 7 and 8 on the modules help. But if you are having issues I can expand on how to alter the template for each version.

- https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_menu
- https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_menus